# Browser's address bar behaviour after redirection

Tags: ruby, redirect, browser, standards

What should be the correct behaviour for a web browser's address bar when the server sends a redirection? (specifically `redirect_to TARGET` controller code in a Ruby on Rails app).
Should the Browser keep the original URL or updates it with the new one? Desktop browsers seems like they use the latest option, but I have an embedded browser that doesn't change it. Is this wrong or it's only unspecified behaviour?

Comment: This is most likely a browser preference. If there is a standard for that, should be about the "current page", not how it is show on your browser.